# Unable to connect Nodejs Socket io server(Openshift free account) from android client

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io, openshift

Developing chat application using nodejs socket io as server, Android as client device.

deployed server in Openshift(free account)..and able to connect server from web application, unable to connect server from android.

i took reference from https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://xxx-xxx.rhcloud.com:8000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { origins: 'http://xxx-xxx.rhcloud.com:8000' });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chatmessage', function (msg) {      
        console.log(msg);       
        io.emit('chatmessage', msg);
    });
server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);
```

Android Client:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    try {           
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://xxx-xxx.rhcloud.com:8000");
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.on("chatmessage", Test);
        mSocket.emit("chatmessage", "xxxxxxxxxxx");

        mTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_test);
        mTxtView.setText("test.....");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error=" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
private Emitter.Listener Test = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Gson j = new Gson();
                String s = j.toJson(args[0]);
                String username;
                String message;                   
                mTxtView.setText(s);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Android Logcat:

```
 I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
04-10 18:31:25.990 32324-1181/example.com.chatsocketio D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: xxx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com get result from proxy >>
 I/System.out: propertyValue:true
 I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
 I/System.out: [socket][13] connection xxx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000;LocalPort=51588(10000)
 I/System.out: [CDS]connect[xxx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000] tm:10
 D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process example.com.chatsocketio :8000 
 I/System.out: [socket][/10.0.0.12:51588] connected
 I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
 I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
 I/System.out: [CDS]close[51588]
 I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
```

Note: I have successfully connected to to server from web application, but it is not connected from Android

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As you already developed your web app, you may don't want to consider my answer and make step back, but I wrote a tutorial to connect an Android client with a Node.js net server (without any external library):

[**https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/04/27/node-js-android-tcpip/**](https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/04/27/node-js-android-tcpip/)

Good luck anyway!